# Run method on background thread every x seconds

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I want to run a method every 3 seconds on a background thread. I already got this code:

```
Timer Order_Timer = new Timer();
Order_Timer.Interval = 3000;
Order_Timer.Elapsed += LoadOrders;
Order_Timer.Enabled = true;
```

With this method:

```
public void LoadOrders(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //My code
}
```

**UPDATE**
I already tried this:

```
Timer Order_Timer = new Timer();
Order_Timer.Interval = 3000;
Order_Timer.Elapsed += ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => LoadOrders(null, null));
Order_Timer.Enabled = true;
```

But that gives the error:

> 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Timers.Timer' and
>   'System.Threading.Timer'

How can I run this on a background thread?

**AWNSER**

I already found it:

```
System.Threading.Timer Order_Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(LoadOrders), null, 2000, 3000);
```

with the method:

```
public void LoadOrders(object state)
{
```

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/writing-responsive-apps

Comment: I already saw that, but how can I mix it up with a timer?

Comment: You don't want to mix them, instead you should replace it by background thread. Also, can you add some more details on how do you control the flow? (Do you ever want to stop and resume this?) And, if you are updating ui (and what)?

Comment: I already found it.... I added the awnser to my question. But thanks for your feedback!

Comment: you should submit your answer as a reply to this post, and mark it as the answer. So it marks the question as 'answered'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found it:

```
System.Threading.Timer Order_Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(LoadOrders), null, 2000, 3000);
```

with the method:

```
public void LoadOrders(object state)
{
```